# PHP Curl prints extra character

Tags: php, curl

I m using this code to print the contents of a page (Also pass `POST` and `COOKIE`). But it gives an extra "`1`" at the  end of the content.

**PHP CODE**

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $fields = array( );

    $fields_string = '';
    $post_count =0;
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $fields_string .= 'fb_app=1';
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST)+1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string );

    $cookie_string="";
    foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $value )   $cookie_string .= "$key=$value;";
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_string);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
echo file_get_contents_curl('http://example.com/my_page/');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world.</p>
    </body>
</html>
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from https://www.php.net/curl_exec

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
> success, FALSE on failure.

So you need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to return the html (instead of true, which prints as a 1) from `curl_exec`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```